# How to use variable in href and pass to click event function to javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

I have several href links in my jade and each link is generated using a variable passed in by some variables.

The code in jade is like this:

```
each rows in meters
    li: a#myLink(href= "/meters/" + rows.meterID)= rows.metername
```

So in my JavaScript part, I added a event listener to each link so that want to generate different pages according to the variables. So that I can add an event listener and emit that variable using socket like this:

```
  document.getElementById("myLink").addEventListener("click", function(){
     document.getElementById("visualization").innerHTML = "";
     socket.emit('building', window.location.pathname);
  });
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: if i understand your question correctly, you want the value of href in the click event right? if thats the case, u can get it from $(this).prop('href')

Comment: You're creating multiple anchors with the same ID

Comment: Could you add the compiled jade output?